# How to remove a character from values in list of dictionaries faster?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries. From which I would like to remove the commas and replicate the list.

I used a for loop to get values with commas removed, named it L1

```
for a in original_list:
        l1.append(a.get('name').replace(',', ''))
```

Created a new list of dictionaries[N1] with key 'name' and values from L1
get each key-value pair from list whose key != 'name' and put it in a separate list S1
Combined S1 and N1

It worked, but was very tedious. Also took a while to loop through my 3000 lines of data.

Is there a way to achieve this quickly?

What I had

```
[
    {}...,
    {'id': 93557, 'name': 'Ryan', 'address':'sth'},
    {'name': 'Harry, jr'},  // comma after Fname
    {'name': 'sam, jr'}, 
    {'name': 'Norton,'},  
    {'name': 'Key, jr,'}, // commas after fname and lname
    {'name': ', jr'}, ... // comma before mname
    ]
```

What I want:

```
[
        {}...,
        {'id': 93557, 'name': 'Ryan', 'address':'sth'},
        {'name': 'Harry jr'}, 
        {'name': 'sam jr'}, 
        {'name': 'Norton'}, 
        {'name': 'Key jr'}, 
        {'name': ' jr'}, ...
 ]
```

Comment: That's not creating a list of dictionaries, it's just creating a list of names.

Comment: Is there always a `name` key? If not, what should be the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the reasons your code takes so long to execute is that you make a new list each time, with a new dict. In-place operations will considerably speed things up for you:

```
for i,d in enumerate(original_list):
    original_list[i]['name'] = d.get('name', '').replace(',','')
```

Comment: Note: If any of the dictionaries don't have a `name` key, this will add one with an empty string as the value.

Comment: @Barmar seems to be what OP wants, based on the sample code provided

Comment: The sample code will get an error if any of the dictionaries don't have a `name` key. Because `d.get('name')` will return `None`, and that doesn't have a `replace()` method.

Comment: I suspect the dictionaries always have `name` so it's moot.

Comment: Thank you for the answer I was not aware of enumerate() attribute. This is what I wanted. And, @Barmar thank you for pointing out the extra addition code might make if 'name' not present; fortunately, 'name' attribute will be present.

Comment: There's actually no need to use `enumerate()` here.

Comment: Just use `for d in original_list: d['name'] = d.get(...).replace(...)`